# What method can I use, (Maptitude is my software) to find the total miles of each roadway within an area?

Tags: maptitude

I have a clipped roadway to an area polygon. I need to calculate total miles within this area. I am using Maptitude for Redistricting.

Answer (score 0):

Open dataview and selection set of roads, Dataview-Tools-Group by-